# Azure deleted & created resources

Tags: azure

I want to have a control in Azure regarding new and deleted items

I need a query to know "who" and "when" a resource is created or deleted in Azure

Is this possible? How can I do this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need a query to know "who" and "when" a resource is created or
>   deleted in Azure
>
> Is this possible? How can I do this query?

Whenever a resource is created or deleted, information about that operation is stored in [`Azure Activity Logs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/platform-logs-overview). You should be able to find the information by [`querying`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-view) that.

Another alternative would be to make use of `Azure Event Grid` and subscribe to [`Subscription Events`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-subscriptions). You can subscribe to `Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess` (for creation/updation of resources) and `Microsoft.Resources.ResourceDeleteSuccess` (for resource deletion) events and take action on these events in near real time.

Answer (score 2):

Within the Azure Portal, you can view these types of events from the past 90 days in the [Activity Log blade](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_ActivityLog/ActivityLogBlade).

For access to events occurring more than 90 days in the past, you need to pre-emptively set up log archival as detailed in the [Export the Azure Activity Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-export) article.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use the export Activity Log feature, please make sure you use the new diagnostic setting feature on Azure subscription to export Activity Logs. This feature offers multiple improvements over the old features such as Logprofiles or the Activity Log solution (Log Analytics).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-collect
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings-template